# How to get Live indetity for TFS collection member who is using live.com account

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I am reading user identities from "Project Collection Valid  Users" group in TFS. As it is TFSPreview, it contains not only TFS identities but also live id. How do I get identities by live id. My user read code is as follows:

```
private void LoadTFSUsers()
{
    string groupName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(configuration.ValidUserGroup) 
                            ? "Project Collection Valid Users" 
                            : configuration.ValidUserGroup;

    Identity SIDS = project.GSS.ReadIdentity(SearchFactor.AccountName, groupName, QueryMembership.Expanded);

    _TFSUsers = project.GSS.ReadIdentities(SearchFactor.Sid, SIDS.Members, QueryMembership.None);
}
```

The result of such query is array of valid members and null values, null values are there because of the live id's. TFS cannot resolve them, maybe someone has an idea how to approach this.

[image: SID's]

[image: Identities]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no answers were provided I will answer with my own solution. What I have found was that this approach was old and unreliable especially after TFS 2013 upgrade 2. So I had to switch to **IdentityManagementService** instead of **GroupSecurityService**. The IMS interface differs slightly due to Identity class exposing less fields but after quick refactor it is pretty much the same.